# Referenced DLL in asp .net web Works in VStudio Server, but not in other server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, dll

Scenario: I have a dll that is added as Referenced to an asp .net Visual Studio 2015 project. I can use the DLL from the client via a handler to return some information from the server. This works fine when I Debug -> Run either debug or release, it works. However, i have created a site in IIS using a specific port. SO when I localhost:58051 to that IIS created site, the DLL does not work. I can't be more specific since I am not sure it is is not called, crashing, or anything else, nothing basically happens.

Do anyone have some suggestions? I'm guessing I missed something in IIS, but not sure what. 
TIA

Answer (score 0):

Got it - actually the DLL does work, but it was launching a COM object that failed behind the scenes. The com object's security was not setup correctly. See http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/Logon/code/code_80070005.htm

For reference, do this is what worked:
DCOM Configuration

1. Click Start -> Run
2. Enter DCOMCNFG and press OK. This will open the DCOMCNFG window.
3. Browse down the tree to Console Root -> Component Services -> Computers -> My Computer
4. right-click on "My Computer" and select properties
5. Select the "Default Properties" tab
   a. Enable Distributed COM on this computer - Option is checked
   b. Default Authentication Level - Set to Connect
   c. Default Impersonation Level - Set to Identify
6. Select the "COM Security" tab
7. Click on Access Permissions ' Edit Default
   a. Add "Anonymous", "Everyone", "Interactive", "Network", "System" with Local and Remote access permissions set.
8. Click on Launch and Activation Permissions ' Edit Default
   a. Add "Anonymous", "Everyone", "Interactive", "Network", "System" with Local and Remote access permissions set.
9. Click on OK
10. Close the DCOMCNFG window